# How to compare two files, one has different fields and other is a c file, using shell script?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the following two files:

File1:

```
#include<stdio.h>   printf,scanf
#include<string.h>  strcpy,strcat,strlen
#include<time.h>    time
```

File2.c:

```
int main {
    char str1[20] = "BeginnersBook";
    printf("Length of string str1: %d", strlen(str1));
    return 0;
}
```

We have to search for the functions of file1 (field2) in file2. If they exist then we should write the result to a different file named output. It should contain only the filename and the appropriate header file should be there like

```
File2:headerfile1,headerfile2
```

It this possible to do with `grep` and `awk`?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you mean. Please try to give a [mcve] together with what you tried and what is the exact output you need.

Comment: No, it is impossible to do this job robustly without a C parser. For example, without parsing the language no text-processing tool can robustly tell if a function name actually appears as a function call vs as part of a string or in a comment (e.g. `time` should not be found if your printf formatting string was `printf("It's time to print the length of string str1: %d", strlen(str1));`. You need to use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) or similar to find the function calls from the C code and then you can write a tool to map those to the list from File1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following script

```
#!/bin/sh
HEAD=
while read p; do
    i=1;
    for word in $p;do
        if [ "$i" = "1" ];then
            HEAD=$word
            echo "header = $HEAD"
        else
            FOUND=0
            for j in $(echo "$word" | tr "," "\n");do
                if grep -Fq "$j" file2.c
                then
                    FOUND=1
                fi
                if ["$FOUND" = "1" ];then
                    #write it into your c file; I am skipping that code
                fi
            done
        fi
        i=0
    done
done < file1
```

Comment: That would not come close to, nor even be in the right direction of, a solution to this problem. Also, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You could transform file1 into a list of patterns (one per line) and use that as an argument to

```
grep -f patterns file2
```

Comment: Skip first word and itrate through comma seperated lines. Do it for every line

Comment: That would not come close to, nor even be in the right direction of, a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Ed Morton 2 How so? I'm pretty sure it could be done.

Comment: One small example: How is grep ever going to be able to tell if the word `time` occurs within a string (`char *foo="this time(or next) we increment i";`) or a comment (`/* we don't use time() because... */`) vs as a function call `time()`? It simply cannot be done without a parser for the language and that parser even has to know which version of the language it's parsing to know what the constructs mean (e.g. `//` means something different in K&R C than in C99).

Comment: @EdMorton Granted, grepping is not the same as parsing, but the OP is looking for a simple solution, possibly for homework.

Comment: I think when you talk about a `simple solution` the emphasis needs to be on `solution` though, not `simple`. You just can't do this job with grep. It is, however, quite trivial with [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) in a small shell script.

Comment: @EdMorton Point conceded.